# How to color links in SankeyNetwork Flow in R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am not able to give colour to the links, although by fluke I have been able to colour the nodes.

```
my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal()
   .domain(["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"])
   .range(["blue", "pink", "green", "purple", "orange"])'

sankeyNetwork(Links = l3, Nodes = n3,
          Source = 'source',
          Target = 'target',
          Value = 'value',
          NodeID = 'name',
          units = 'ValueUSD',
          fontSize = 12,
          colourScale = my_color)
```

colour of nodes appears but no idea how to get links coloured. I want the colour of the links to be based on the year, not based on the countries.

[image: the output]

Answer (score 1):

Taken from "Set color of connections" [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/322-custom-colours-in-sankey-diagram.html)

```
# Library
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

# Make a connection data frame
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("group_A","group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_C", "group_E"), 
  target=c("group_C","group_D", "group_E", "group_F", "group_G", "group_H"), 
  value=c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)
 
# From these flows we need to create a node data frame: it lists every entities involved in the flow
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) %>% 
    unique()
)

# With networkD3, connection must be provided using id, not using real name like in the links dataframe.. So we need to reformat it.
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

# Add a 'group' column to each connection:
links$group <- as.factor(c("type_a","type_a","type_a","type_b","type_b","type_b"))
 
# Add a 'group' column to each node. Here I decide to put all of them in the same group to make them grey
nodes$group <- as.factor(c("my_unique_group"))
 
# Give a color for each group:
my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(["type_a", "type_b", "my_unique_group"]) .range(["#69b3a2", "steelblue", "grey"])'
 
# Make the Network
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget", 
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                   colourScale=my_color, LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup="group")

p
```

Answer (score 0):

Options in SankeyNetwork from the NetworkD3 package are limited. I suggest looking into the 'plotly' package. Here you can find some examples: https://plot.ly/~alishobeiri/1591/plotly-sankey-diagrams/#/